# phpMyAdmin com Xdebug lento em Windows 8.1 com Xampp

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Boas,
À uns tempos atrás reparei que o meu phpMyAdmin estava estupidamente lento (mais de meio minuto numa consulta simples)... Depois de pesquisar sobre isso, cheguei à conclusão que se devia a ter o XDebug ligado nas configurações do PHP.ini... Comentei tudo e voltou tudo à normalidade!

Contudo ultimamente tenho necessitado bastante do XDebug e também do phpMyAdmin, e torna-se chato de cada vez que preciso de usar um ou outro ter de ir ao php.ini comentar ou descomentar o XDebug...

Alguém me consegue dizer alguma forma de contornar este problema?

Existe alguma definição do XDebug que está a mais ou que possa estar a dar estes problemas?

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

Utilizo o Windows 8.1 (64bits), Xampp 1.8.3 (PHP 5.5.15, MySQL 5.6.20, Apache 2.4.10)... 
Obrigado em avanço!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acordo com essa resposta no [SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19273025/4336024), é preciso desabilitar a auto-inicialização do debugador remoto:

```
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
```

Comment: Boa! Resolveu! Ficou bem mais rápido!
Obrigado!